# Covering Subreport with Text Object PROBLEM

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, subreport

What can I do for subreport so that When i click on it, it won't appear on the seperate page?

I actually found a way but it is really ugly and not convenient for long reports.

My way is that.. I cover the subreport with a text object. And extends the length of text object depends on how many rows the subreport have.

It is work fine till some time.

For eg, My report has over 100 rows. If i only show up to 90 rows, it is ok. If i show over 90 rows, the error message pop up.[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a47646b658.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a47646b658.jpg)

I think the length of the text cannot follow up.
Could anybody tell me why?

Comment: actually I know the reason. The reason is the height of a section is limited to 32K. So more than that, there will be an error. But is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the height of a section is limited to 32K. So more than that, there will be an error.

If there is 2 reports, then one of them should be a short one.
Make it a sub report and cover with the text object.

Make sure that it won't be over 32K of length.